# Changing default text style in storyboard?

Tags: ios, ios7

Is it possible to change the storyboard default text styles so they reflect my own 6 fonts?

[image]

Comment: If this helped you, or if this is the best answer for this topic, can you throw the check my way? If not, can you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

To do so, you're going to have to use an XCode plugin such as [this one](https://github.com/deni2s/IBCustomFonts). Otherwise, no, you cannot.